# Pandas: Filling column in dataset with data from another dataset based on matching columns in the two datasets

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble trying to figure out this problem.

I have two datasets, dataset_1 and dataset_2. I am trying to create a new column in dataset_1 called 'name' by matching the 'id's from Dataset_1 and Dataset_2. Essentially mapping the names to their corresponding ids.

There are around 10 other columns in each dataframe, but they're not necessary for this question.

Examples of the columns in the datasets:

Dataset_1:

```
id: 
1234
3267
12
1234
15
```

Dataset_2:

```
id:         name:
12          jimbo
899         jim
3267        jimmy
1234        jimbob
899         jim
```

Resulting dataframe:

Dataset_1:

```
id:        name:
1234       jimbob
3267       jimmy 
12         jimbo
1234       jimbo
15         jahad
```

(assuming the name 15 - "jahad" is further down in Dataset_2)

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dictionary from the two columns in `df2` and use to `map` the values in `df1`:

```
print(df1)
    id
0  1234
1  3267
2    12
3  1234
4    15

print(df2)
     id    name
0    12   jimbo
1   899     jim
2  3267   jimmy
3  1234  jimbob
4   899     jim

mapper = dict(zip(df2.id, df2.name))
# {12: 'jimbo', 899: 'jim', 3267: 'jimmy', 1234: 'jimbob'}

df1.loc[:,'name'] = df1.id.map(mapper)

    id    name
0  1234  jimbob
1  3267   jimmy
2    12   jimbo
3  1234  jimbob
4    15     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the left join(pd.merge) in one line of code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1234, 3267, 12, 1234, 15]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [12, 899, 3267, 1234, 899, 15],
    'name': ['jimbo', 'jim', 'jimmy', 'jimbob', 'jim', 'jahad']
})

df = df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left')

print(df)
```

Results:
[image]